# Crash Mac application at the time of Sqlite Interaction

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite database in my mac application for locally storage.When I perform insert operation in sqlite database then it get crashed. Following is the detail of crashed thread :-

> 0   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x925602e5 sqlite3BitvecSet +
>   21 1   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x92560f04 pager_write +
>   1060 2   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x925614fa
>   sqlite3PagerWrite + 842 3   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x925661f8 insertCell + 152 4   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x9257f78e sqlite3BtreeInsert + 1102 5   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x925dadd4 sqlite3VdbeExec + 28548 6   libsqlite3.dylib
>   0x925e0867 sqlite3_step + 1639 7   com.tprf.RCS
>   0x002e9934 -[LocalDBController performingInsertionInLocalForQuery:] +
>   209 (LocalDBController.m:4630)

I am using following step to perform a insertion:-

> sqlite3_stmt *insertStmnt;        const char *sql = [insertQuery
>   cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>                 if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insertStmnt, NULL) ==
>   SQLITE_OK){
>                     }else{
>                     }       if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmnt)){       }

Please suggest me how to resolve the crash problem...

Thanks in advance